# Всплывающие блоки

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.Делаю сайт и появилась необходимость сделать удобную для пользователя функцию добавления различных записей. Вот [пример](http://remontnik.ru/). Там на главной странице в самом верху есть блок для добавления заказа. Суть в том, что там заполняются только основные поля (заголовок, описание и город заказа). А уже после нажатия на кнопку добавления, всплывает блок, где нужно ввести более подробную информацию по заказу. Хочу так же сделать у себя. Подскажите, как лучше все это дело реализовать? Лучше писать самому или есть готовые плагины для таких вещей??

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написал сам... Лишняя практика не помешает :)
Но если других дел много сроки ограничены или в JS вы "не специалист" лучше использовать готовые библиотеки, например [плагин JQuery Window](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего - начать уже реализовывать. Если вИдения еще нет - оно появится в процессе работы. Хотите двойную форму - делайте двойную.

Собственно, вооружайтесь Fibebug'ом и изучайте код страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Ну это обычный плагин к `jquery` вроде `fancybox`. Такой можно написать вручную или использовать готовый, зависит от ваших возможностей и свободного времени.